# Rewriting audio data to wav file adds a lot of noise

Tags: c#, audio-processing

I want to make an application that reads the audio samples one by one manipulate them and than writing the new samples to a WAV file. However, when I tried to do this I only received white noise.

I tried to find whether the problem was with the manipulation or with the reading so I tried to simply extract data and rewrite to WAV (without changing the data) and I received a lot of white noise in addition to the original sound.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] arrfile = new byte[fs.Length - 44];
fs.Position = 44;
fs.Read(arrfile, 0, arrfile.Length);
fs.Close();

FileStream fo = new FileStream(@outfile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fo);
bw.Write(arrfile);
bw.Close();
fo.Close();
```

Comment: Do you get the entire sound byte?  The quality of the sound is in the byte[], so maybe a 24bit sound recording is being transmitted from a 16bit sender? Your code has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: that's probably the problem because the file is 2822 kbps which means it's 32bit ,how can i fix it?

Comment: Ya it sounds like you are using a 28K baud modem with converts to 16 bit automatically.  Don't use that modem or "dial up link" use the internet instead.